# How to define and compute radius of convergence of double power series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let's consider following double power series:
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{nk}t^{f(n,k)}$$
where $f(n,k)$ - some linear funkction of $n$ and $k$ (increasing in $n$ and $k$ directions), $t$ - real number.

1) How to define radius of convergence of such series?

2) How to compute radius of convergence?

3) How to compute radius of convergence for $a_{nk} = \frac{(-a)^k(-b)^n{ n+k \choose k}}{\Gamma(2n+(2-\alpha)k+2)}$ and $f(n,k) = 2n+(2-\alpha)k$, where $a,b>0$, $0<\alpha<1$, $\Gamma$ - Gamma function?